# What does pilot price mean in the context of marketing?

Tags: competition, price, marketing

In my lecture slide, it is said to be one of the competition-based price determination.

When I searched online, I was unable to find anything relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the phrase [pilot experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot_experiment)
or more famously [television pilot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Television_pilot) is any indication, then pilot price is probably an initial price, one that the company experiments with when trying to find the ideal price of their product.